# tensorflow tensor operations - tiling with dimension object does not work?

Tags: tensorflow

I Have a matrix M:

```
[[101,  51, 12],
 [101,  19, 18]]
```

Long story short, I need to create the following with tensorflow syntax:

```
[[0, 0, 101],
 [0, 1, 51],
 [0, 2, 12],
 [1, 0, 101],
 [1, 1, 19],
 [1, 2, 18]]
```

My approach was to create 3 seperate vectors and join them to produce the above:

```
v1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

v2 = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

and

M_flat = [101, 51, 12, 101, 19, 18]
```

I can get `M_flat = [101, 51, 12, 101, 19, 18]` using `tf.reshape(M, shape=(-1,))`

I do not know the dimensions of M in advance, so I use the following syntax to obtain it:

```
dim0 = M.get_shape()[0]
dim1 = M.get_shape()[1]
```

From this I can obtain `[0, 1, 2]` via

```
tf.range(dim1)
```

To get `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]` I tried tiling:

```
tf.tile(tf.range(dim1), [dim0])
```

However, this does not work because `dim0` is a dimension object, and `tile` wants an integer so I get the error `Expected binary or unicode string, got Dimension(100)`

Additionally, I am not sure if `tile` can be used to produce this `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` (maybe some reshapes, transposes, and tiling can though, again assuming those operations can work off of `dim0` and `dim1` instead of explicit numbers)

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: would you please post your code that replicates this error ? It will be helpful for people to make few changes to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error, you can just access the `value` of the  `Dimension` object through something like this `M.get_shape[0].value`.

For what concerns the `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` you can do very similarly to what you have already done with `tf.tile` (just tile on another axis).

You can obtain your result as follows (written very fast but should do the job):

```
M = tf.convert_to_tensor([[101, 51, 12], [101, 19, 18]])
dim0 = M.get_shape()[0].value
dim1 = M.get_shape()[1].value
r0 = tf.range(dim0)
r0x = tf.expand_dims(r0,1)
A = tf.reshape(tf.tile(r0x, [1, dim1]), [-1, 1])  # A = [[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1]]
r1 = tf.range(dim1)
r1x = tf.expand_dims(r1,1)
B = tf.reshape(tf.tile(r1x, [dim0, 1]), [-1, 1])  # B = [[0],[1],[2],[0],[1],[2]]
M = tf.reshape(M, [-1, 1])
res = tf.concat((A, B, M), axis=1)
```